# Allowing only my Unity Game to access web files through .htaccess

Tags: c#, php, .htaccess, unity-game-engine, apache2

**<sub>(This has been answered, but if anyone has a better way without hard-coding a username and password that would be nice)</sub>**



I'm making a Mobile game in Unity3D (written in c#). This game can connect to my server to check/save scores in an online database. (Server is ubuntu running Apache2)

---

But here is the problem:

Whenever i go to `http://SERVER_IP/WEB_NAME` i can see all my files in the browser and that is not really safe.. I tried to make a .htaccess with `"Deny from All"`, but that also blocks my game from using any files in that folder..

---

Here is my question:

How can i make sure only my game can use these files and not someone from the outside that goes to `http://SERVER_IP/WEB_NAME` ?

---

Resources:

- Apache2.conf: http://pastebin.com/1ZQhNGa4

---

Thanks in Advance!

**~ JohnDoe**

Comment: you must share config of your apache2 web server for more understand...

Comment: It really depends how secure you want the endpoint to be. You could use various techniques. But if you're running a server side app to save the scores it would probably be better to write authentication into app & server and send credentials or an access token along with the post data which is then checked by the server side app.

Comment: @darkomen I added my apache2.conf, is that enough?

Comment: @Rob Yes that was something i was considering, but people will still be able to see the inside of my web folder by following `http://SERVER_IP/WEB_NAME`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using [`WWWForm`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html) in Unity
You can use something like HTTP basic auth.
It's not super secure but it will prevent anyone simply accessing your endpoint via a web browser.

Let create a simple example with a Coroutine:

```c#
void SaveData()
{
    StartCoroutine(SubmitData());
}

IEnumerator SubmitData()
{
  // create and instance of WWWForm
  WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
  // Add Some data
  form.AddField( "playerName", "Bob" );
  form.AddField( "playerScore", 100 );

  //Get reference to headers so we can modify them.
  Hashtable headers = form.headers;
  byte[] rawData = form.data;
  string url = "SERVER_IP/WEB_NAME";

  //Add the authorisation header with username/password to access the endpoint
  headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password"));

  // Post the request
  WWW www = new WWW(url, rawData, headers);
  yield return www;
}
```

No in .htaccess we setup apache to check the authorisation using mod_auth_basic

Here's an example `.htaccess` file you should put on your server.
You'll also need a `.htpasswd` file that is not publicly accessible that contains the username and password.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

You can use [a generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) to create a `.htpasswd` file

Comment: This looks promising.. I'm not using WWWForm anymore, because i needed to do this stuff on a different Thread. 

I'm going to try this out and check back with you!

Thanks

Comment: Use a `Coroutine` to prevent main thread blocking. Also have a read through unity docs on [web requests](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html), it explains the concept nicely (about 1/3rd of the way down the page)

Comment: Thanks for the info, but i have had my experiences with `Coroutines` and i have tried alot to make them fit for my purpose (and so learned alot :) ).. Sadly they didnt, but now i have a fully working Thread system but this is all off-topic

Comment: So i managed to create these Authorization headers and all seems working, my game can access the server files and if you just navigate to the server you'll need to login. I'll mark this is an answer, but if anyone has a better way without hard-coding a username and password that would be nice!

Comment: @JohnDoe Do not hardcode the username and password. Remember Reverse Engineer is as easy as counting ABCD. Learn MySql then make the player register. That way, if the player access the server with many devices/multiple session, then you can ban them. If you don't do that, any one can get the username and password and then be able to access the files again. Rob's answer is good. Just replace the username/password hardcoding part with mysql server. I cringed when I saw that part.

Comment: @Programmer ah ofcourse! Thanks! Well i got all those things already setup (mysql, registering player etc), so it wont be hard to add this in. And yes i know how "easy" Reverse Enginering is so that is why i said i preferred a non-hardcoding method, but this answer still helped me to get in the right direction (i never really liked those "complete copy paste" answers because you never learn something from them..)  Thanks again for the TIP :)

Comment: Samsung did hardcoded password for their printers few years and it took just days for some crazy guy to discover password..... Glad you know what you are doing. mysql and php is a must to know language for Unity programmers. Good luck with your game.

Comment: @JohnDoe like I said it is not 100% secure approach but you're never going to get that with embedded access tokens, effectively your security is just obfuscated in the code. Best way would be write your own OAuth layer requiring the player to actually login, Alternatively use a social game platform like Google Play/Game Center. That way you can use their APIs on your server side app to check against the users access token in the game. (That's what I use, but they also tie you in there's pros/cons to everything) Likewise, Google luck!

Comment: @Rob i have looked into the play/game center, but i came to the conclusion i wanted to make my own systems for that so i can learn how they work. And yes i know this is not recommended beceause most of the times you end up using 3rd party software BUT i think you should make some mistakes first to learn from them ;).

Comment: @JohnDoe agreed, I applaud you for taking the initiative and writing something yourself.